On tuesday fast for hanuman ji, can we eat dry fruits like almond, cahew without salt
Can we eat cashews, almonds and fruits on tuesday when fasting for Hanuman ji? How many times we can drink tea or coffee in a day?
Fasting for first time.

Yes you can .. eating salt breaks the fast as you already know .. drinking tea etc.is allowed in a nirjala fast
